# Closed form of negative root of $x+x^2+x^4+x^8+x^{16}+...=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, polynomials, power-series, closed-form

I was investiging the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty{x^{(2^k)}}$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and came up with this question:

> Is there a closed form of the negative root of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty{x^{(2^k)}}=0$ ?

On Desmos, taking the first $5$ terms, and taking the first $1001$ terms, both give the negative root as $-0.6586$ to $4$ decimal places.

[image]

Here are my thoughts. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem), "there is no solution in radicals to general polynomial equations of degree five or higher with arbitrary coefficients". So if we take the first five terms of the series, I would not expect a closed form of the negative root. But, based on my experience with power series, if we take the limit as the number of terms approaches $\infty$, I would be more inclined to believe that a closed form might exist.

Comment: "there is no solution in radicals to general polynomial equations of degree five or higher with arbitrary coefficients" -- In general, this is true. However, it makes assumptions on the kinds of functions/operations permissible, and this is a *general* statement about a formula working for *all possible quintic polynomials* (of certain coefficients). Closed forms may exist for special cases, the obvious one being $f(x) = x^n - 1$ having a root at $x=1$ always. Consequently, I wouldn't take the insolvability of the quintic as a reason to believe a closed form does not exist for this.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Agreed. To clarify: If we take the first five terms of the series, I would not expect that a closed form must exist.

Comment: The tenth term evaluated at the root is already pretty small, $(-0.6586)^{512} = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000136\ldots$, so taking $1001$ terms won't make much of a difference.

Comment: The [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1982-39-159/S0025-5718-1982-0658225-3/S0025-5718-1982-0658225-3.pdf) linked in this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/178561) on MSO lists the negative root $−0.6586...$ numerically, not mentioning a closed form or other references.

Comment: I will be surprised if it admits a closed-form expression. Indeed, $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{2^n}$ is a quintessential example of [lacunary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function). Since most, if not all, well-studied special functions do not show lacunary behavior, I believe that $f$ is not linked to any such functions. It seems to me that this strongly suggests that the negative zero of $f$ is not linked to such special functions.

Comment: as @EveeTrainer mentions polynomials can in general only be sure to be solved in finite number of steps of */-+ and roots if they are degree 4 or less, but if other things are allowed such as transcendental functions, trigonometric polynomials and others, closed forms could exist for larger degrees as well.

Comment: $A339253$ in $OEIS$ gives $86$ digits

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks - good idea to check OEIS (I had checked Wolfram, but hadn't thought about checking OEIS). Of course, appearing in OEIS does not mean there is no closed form (e.g. $\pi$). Incidentally, the coordinates of the minimum point on the curve $(-0.3828964..., -0.2143301...)$, do not appear in OEIS.